# css stops down the page

Tags: html, css

This is what I am trying to describe as my problem, you can see the white content box just kind of stops:

Link to image as I cant put images on here yet:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/534/43094999.png/

The image loaded for that background apparently isn't long enough, and I am not sure how to repeat it down so it all flows.

Here is a peak at my css if that helps in solving the problem:

http://pastebin.com/RwcAPjS5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear floats after the list of boxes. You could do this with an extra element, or by adding the `clear` CSS property to the next sibling element (note that this stops some margins working).

```
.clearfix {
    clear:both
}
```

Then in your HTML (the `ul` is just a guess as I haven't seen your HTML):

```
<ul class="float-boxes">
    <li>...</li>
</ul>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

There's a good article on floats [here](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), which touches on why this happens.

Comment: My css already has this

/* Clear Fix
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0;}*/
.clearboth, .clearfix {clear: both;}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }

and I have this after my boxes:

<div class=\"clearfix\"></div>

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, there's not much else I can suggest. A link to the actual page you're working on (if possible) would be the most useful.

Comment: I think the problem is this `.content-container {background:url(images/content-bg.png) top left no-repeat; ... }` You need to replace `no-repeat` with `repeat-y`. Once you've done this, you can make the background image very short and it will tile. On a side note, please consider using pre-resized images instead of resizing on the `img` tag; the images you are using are twice the size (and hence twice the data) that they need to be.

Comment: That made it better, but it repeats the image and places a gap. As seen in attached picture:

http://imgur.com/dTqDc

Comment: The code is working perfectly; you need to adjust the image so it tiles nicely. You may need to add another element to the top of the content box to retain that top edge.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will play around with it some more and see what I can do

Comment: So I haven't been able to figure this out. If you have time and can help me out any more I would appreciate it

Comment: Assuming it still looks like the last image you linked, you need to separate the top with rounded corners from the longer (content) part the background image. You don't need much of the content part, since it will automatically be repeated by your CSS. You should end up with a [repeatable slice](http://i.imgur.com/6liuH.png) and a [top slice](http://i.imgur.com/9h0gh.png). Set the element's background image to the repeatable slice, then add an `img` or `div` element to the top of that container using the top slice as the (background) image.